# C# (not ASP/MVC/WinForms) - Catch all exceptions in a class

Tags: c#, .net, exception

#### Some background info

I am programming in a system that uses a proprietary programming language, with the option of using specially attributed .Net classes in the proprietary code.

Unfortunately, the system doesn't handle unhandled exceptions bubbling up from .Net code well, if fact not at all; the system crashes with no explanation. This is annoying, because we often want to handle exceptions in the *proprietary system*, not in .Net code. The solution offered by the vendor of the system is to repackage the exception into a special object that the system *does* handle.

Our .Net code is written in a façade pattern, and the problem is that to make sure every exception that bubbles up from the .Net code is handled, every method in the facade must include a try/catch block that repackages any exceptions that may occur.

#### The question

I've read a lot of threads here describing similar scenarios, most of them WinForms- or web-related. Because our code is neither, the question is if there is some way to catch all exceptions in a class, so that we can repackage it and rethrow a modified version of them?

Obviously, the interface between the .Net dll's containing the classes and the proprietary language is completely beyond our control.

#### Edit

I tried the `currentDomain.UnhandledException` method suggested by @VMAtm, unfortunately to no avail. The event handler didn't fire, and the parent system got hold of the exception and then misbehaved as usual. That led me onto Google once more, and I found this paragraph [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/02/console-apps-and-appdomaincurrentdomainunhandledexception.html):

> The first thing to understand is that the UnhandledException event is not an unhandled exception "handler". Registering for the event, contrary to what the documentation says :-(, does not cause unhandled exceptions to be handled. (Since then they wouldn't be unhandled, but I'll stop with the circular reasoning already...) The UnhandledException event simply notifies you that an exception has gone unhandled, in case you want to try to save state before your thread or application dies.
>
> Jonathan Keljo, CLR Exceptions PM

That was too bad, I liked the idea of having a "global" try/catch block. What I guess it means is that I'm not successful in hiding the exception from the parent system. Since I don't know the first thing about how this is implemented in that system (and frankly, I don't know the first thing about how I'd go on to implement it myself) I'm on really thin ice with my assumptions, so if anyone can correct me in any way, please go ahead!

Ohh, the error I'm getting in the parent system is `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`, which is as far as I know the message from the outer .Net exception occurring. If it's possible to read anything out of that, I don't know.

I'll have a go at the Castle Dynamic Proxy suggested by @jlew as well, but it looked a lot harder than the two AppDomain lines and scared me quite a bit :)

#### Solution

If you are having the same problem as I had, you should try the `currentDomain.UnhandledException` method suggested by @VMAtm first, because it's because of my parent system being especially anal it didn't work.

I got it working by using the Castle DynamicProxy setup. It was really very easy to set up. My test case was a façade class encapsulating the XmlAttribute class. The first thing I had to do was to write the proxy class:

```
public class AttribInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Custom exception repackaging here
        }
    }
}
```

Then I had to instruct the façade object to actually use the proxy. I kept my old backend field, but added the following to the c'tor:

```
public class CapXmlAttribute : CapPmlNetObject
{
    private XmlAttributeBackend _xmlAttribute;

    public CapXmlAttribute()
    {
        var generator = new ProxyGenerator();
        _xmlAttribute = (XmlAttributeBackend) generator.CreateClassProxy(
            typeof (XmlAttributeBackend), new AttribInterceptor());
    }
}
```

The last step was setting all methods in the backend that is exposed to the façade as `virtual`. This was no problem for me, but might be a dealbreaker for others.

[DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) really isn't that good documented, but I learned a lot from [Krzysztof Koźmic's tutorial](http://kozmic.pl/dynamic-proxy-tutorial/) and [Hamilton Verissimo's codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/hamiltondynamicproxy.aspx).

Comment: Back-patching exception handling into a chunk of code that was designed without any consideration for it just doesn't work well.  If the try/catch doesn't wrap the inner interpreter loop then you're doomed to catch everywhere.  That is indeed completely out of your control.  Check if their runtime supports COM at all, that's usually better handled.

Comment: Maybe you whip up a proxy based on function names and delegates that simply wraps all requests with a Try-Catch block. The proxy can even be made by a code generator simply wrapping all publicly accesible functions in a DLL file/some code.

Comment: Did you try AppDomain.UnhandledException ? Cause if your code, as I understood, is kind of API base for proprietary system. That system have to load it into managed memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take a look at using something like [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html).
This will allow your class method calls to be intercepted in a generic way, which would give you a central place to put a "catch-all" exception handler.  (That said, it's unclear to me how your classes are actually instantiated, which might make this approach problematic)

Comment: The facade class is exposed to and instantiated from the parent system. Being lightweight, it should never throw an exception itself. That means all the relevant exceptions will be thrown by the facade backend, which I instantiates myself. That should bode well, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I'd think that would be doable with CDP

Comment: It worked! And it wasn't nearly as much work as I initially expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11):

As I understood the answer, you need to catch and rethrow unhandled exception, right?
You can add handler for the [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx):

```
  AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
  currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

  static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
  {
        Exception e = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;
        // handle exception here, you can easily package exceptions there.
  }
```

---

Update:

I've discovered another event in `AppDomain` class, [AppDomain.FirstChanceException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx):

> Occurs when an exception is thrown in managed code, before the runtime searches the call stack for an exception handler in the application domain.

May be this can solve your problem - this event occurs **before** any code in `catch` blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @VMAtm! I tried implementing it, but somehow, the handler method never gets called. When stepping through the code, the moment the exception was received in the facade, it got picked up by the host system. Is it possible that they are listening to this event themselves, and so receives it first?

Comment: Well, you must handle the event from `AppDomain` for executing code. May be you will need additional work to get the right AppDomain. But when you get a right AppDomain, you will always catch the event - there is no way to cancel it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to properly hide the exceptions from the parent system. I added some details in the Edit section above. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @joneberg Updated the answer. May be this will help you more.

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to VMAtm's post you can also set event handler for [ThreadExceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)

Comment: This can be a problem because @joneberg asked about not winforms in question.

Comment: @VMAtm: true, I just wanted to mention it, if he only meant to show no dialogs...

Comment: @cevik: Unfortunately, this is plain old classes, no winforms involved. Thanks for the suggestion, though!