# Castle Dynamic Proxy wants to intercept Object.GetType()

Tags: c#, .net, castle-dynamicproxy, proxy-classes

In a project, I'm using a Castle Dynamic Proxy to wrap all code run by a façade in try/catch blocks (sounds odd? Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611215/c-not-asp-mvc-winforms-catch-all-exceptions-in-a-class)). That works fine, but to make sure all method calls are intercepted, I throw an exception when I come across something non-virtual, using the `NonProxyableMemberNotification` method of the `IProxyGenerationHook` interface:

```
public void NonProxyableMemberNotification(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
          "Proxy failure. {0} {1} in {2} is not virtual.", 
          memberInfo.MemberType, memberInfo.Name, memberInfo.DeclaringType));
}
```

According to Krzysztof Koźmic's great [tutorial](http://kozmic.pl/2009/02/23/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-vi-handling-non-virtual-methods); *Object classes are spe­cial cases, and by default Dynam­icProxy will just ignore them*. Problem is, in my case they are not ignored, as seen from the following sample `MemberInfo` data:

[image: memberInfo QuickWatch]

Is there something I've missed here? Is `NonProxyableMemberNotification` supposed to fire on Object methods?

I'm using .Net 3.5, VS2010 and Castle Core version 2.5.2, and I'm not overriding `Object.GetType()` in my `XmlDocumentBackend`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this implementation of NonProxyableMemberNotification:

```
public void NonProxyableMemberNotification(Type type, System.Reflection.MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
        if (memberInfo.DeclaringType != typeof(object))
        {
            string message = string.Format("Non-proxyable member encountered - {0} (type - {1})",
                memberInfo.Name, type.FullName);
            throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial was written for DynamicProxy Version... 2.1 IIRC.

That aspect of DynamicProxy has changed in more recent version as there were situations where methods on System.Object actually needed to be intercepted. (`GerHashCode`, `Equals`, `ToString`...). For that reason DP internally doesn't blacklist `System.Object` from being interceptable and instead relies on the default implementation of `IProxyGenerationHook` (the `AllMethodsHook` class) to do it (so that it can be overridden if needed).

So if you want `System.Object` methods to be pre-filtered just inherit from this class and use `base` implementation.

I can see how this can be confusing though, so I'll see if GetHasCode, being a special case can be easily pre-filtered even before hitting `NonProxyableMemberNotification` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that really explained a lot!